# Adding new record trough the ORM

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Am i blind or nowhere in the mighty google or the play documentation there isn't a single explanation on how to create a new record trough the ORM in play 2.3.6?

Can someone please provide an example ?

Comment: Are you talking about Slick or Ebean?

Comment: I'm talking about Ebean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved** - in case anyone face the same problem finding documentation about Ebean ORM usage in play framework - it's better to look in the Ebean documentation and not play's, it's here:
http://avaje.com/documentation

For this specific example (let's say our Model is `User`):

```
User user = new User();
user.name = "some name";    
user.save();
```